# How to Convert Date To 8 digit integer?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

How can I convert the `Date` 02/14/2012 to this format '20120214'?

I want to save the date in my database as an integer because it seems like it would be more more flexible.

Comment: I would never save a data as MM/DD/YYYY, but are you sure saving it as a text field YYYYMMDD is better than an actual date or datetime field ? Most (if not all ?) db's support datetime.

Comment: He does not say text, he says integer. THer are reasons for text, though, for example different dimensions (20120214 for a day, 201202 for a month, 2012 for a year). Used sometimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2012, 02, 14);
string toDb = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

**Update**
Oh, since there's a comment I urge you to use DateTime fields in database using database engine instead of string format. Storing datetime as text isn't flexible. Some engines (like Sqlite) don't support datetime fields, but most of them do. Using string format for datetime forces you to apply manual parsing and converting wherever you need to fetch value from db or save it to db. It's very easy to forget it once what will lead to bug hard to find. While using datetime field you don't need to remember about it.

Comment: Please care to add a note for using datetime fields in db, it could be flexible now before it transforms into a maintenance hell later on

Comment: Thanks for you're comment guys now I know what to do

Answer (score 1):

Please try.

```
string[] dtPart = "02/14/2012".Split('/');

DateTime dt = new DateTime(int.Parse(dtPart[2]), int.Parse(dtPart[0]), int.Parse(dtPart[1]));
 int result = int.Parse(dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"); then use Convert.ToUInt32 convert to integer if necessary.

But I think DateTime type is better then integer or string in database. then you format DateTime as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Format()` function

More info on `String.Format()` http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom DateTime format string on .ToString for your DateTime instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

`dateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

Almost all databases however have a way of storing a date as a date instead of string and you may want to investigate that.  Keeping dates as date data type will help you avoid potential localization issues and other date related issues if you perform math on dates.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.ToString("yyyMMdd")`

try this one:

```
Msgbox(Now.ToString("yyyMMdd"))
```

Comment: Pedantically, this does not work for years < 1000, where as "yyyyMMdd" does.